# Access on Premise resources using Azure AD Application proxy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

we have configured azure active directory pass-through authentication . Need to access on premise resources from the azure deployed application. can we do this by configuring application proxy?. so that on premise application authenticated with azure AD. so the communication between azure application and on premise application be seamless. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand you correctly but what you want is probably possible by using Azure Hybrid Connections: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections

You install the Hybrid Connector on-prem, e.g. on a VM, and then for instance an Azure App Service can access certain resources on-prem.

Or for anything more advanced you might want to look at Azure VPN (or ExpressRoute in the long run).